# Does Linux TCP stack processing happen before or after netfilter?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, netfilter

The Linux netfilter has multiple hooks at different OSI model layers according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) image.  However, the transportation layer protocols like TCP requires additional processing like retransmission or congestion control.  Does this happen before or after netfilter framework or a specific hook? And why it's designed in such way. Explanation with source code is appreciated.

Comment: If you think about it, what is responsible for accepting connection? TCP/IP stack will need to process the packet before netfilter will be able to do any action of manipulating the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5TvPRQFNoM) from Devconf 2018 with Jiri Benc talking about Linux network pipeline.   TCP is a transport layer protocol; for packets that use it, the network stack must first parse the data link and network layer headers. Then, the `dst_input` determines if the packet is for local processing or forwarding. In slide 62, he mentioned if the packet is for local processing, the TCP state machine will handle it after the `INPUT` hook of the netfilter. Detailed implementation can be found in the `tcp_v4_rcv` function in `linux/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c`.

Answer (score 0):

Even without perusing the source code it's fairly easy to test.

On a machine running with a firewall ruleset permitting certain ports only from e.g. one specific IP stand up a tcpdump for the port in question, and try to connect to the IP:port from a machine that's **not** permitted.

You'll see the incoming request.

Comment: Please show the exact steps of your experiment and the output. BTW, I'm not asking if SYN, ACK packets can go though the firewall, I want to know if the whole TCP stack processing (e.g., header parsing, retransmission or congestion control) happen before or after netfilter or its specific hook.